# How do I get my ships to travel between systems which are not directly connected?

Tags: endless-space

[image]

How do I get my ships to go between systems like the blue and green ships?

Comment: I believe this requires a technology that you have to research.  I'm still a newb, so I don't know which one(s) specifically.

Comment: Im looking for which one

Comment: Yep, I'm sure someone will be along shortly to answer.  Just leaving whatever info I do know as a comment.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to research Atmospheric Filtration.  It is on the Exploration & Expansion branch, but you can use the built in search to find it directly.

Comment: nope, i already have that research.

Comment: That is most definitely the tech that allows off string travel.  Keep in mind, that strings are MUCH faster than traveling through space, so the fastest route will rarely be the direct one.  You can force a ship to fly direct by holding down Ctrl and right clicking on the destination.